# How does Sharepoint now interact with Power BI and SSRS?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am researching the possible implementation of Sharepoint and Power BI for a small company (1000 employees) which has Office 365 and SQL Server 2016. Can you view SSRS and Power BI reports in Sharepoint?  Can you edit them from Sharepoint?  I am trying to figure out how to implement the document control of Sharepoint along with Business Intelligence of Power BI and SSRS.

thanks,
Ginger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS is only supported in on-premises installations of SharePoint Server, it is not support in SharePoint Online see the [official SharePoint Online service description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-service-description).

Power BI is the flagship reporting and analytics tool for the entire O365 suite, including SharePoint Online.  I would suggest starting at [this entry at the Microsoft Power BI Blog](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/integrate-power-bi-reports-in-sharepoint-online/), but there is seemingly infinite more information out there on Power BI usage in SharePoint.

Comment: Also SSRS - SharePoint integration is not supported after SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Willman & Newbie, thanks for your replies.  I followed the link to see the Official SharePoint online description and saw that integrated services SSRS was not supported.  Is it possible to embed an SSRS report in Sharepoint by adding a link to that report?  I'm thinking no, but wanted to be certain.

Comment: Since SSRS surfaces its reports via a web url, assuming your users on a network that has access to your SSRS server, or it is accessible outside your firewall, you can always theoretically use the Page Viewer webpart, which essentially just puts an Iframe on your SharePoint page to display any specified url as a nested webpage.  But there won't be any true integration between SharePoint and the viewed report.