# Does Sharepoint online have manage content databases similar like Sharepoint 2013 or 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, central-administration, content-database, sharepoint-admin-center

I am new to SharePoint.
I would like to migrate WSS_Content databases from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online. How can I do it?
Is there any way to migrate those databases to SharePoint online. Or can I point SharePoint online databases to on-premise.

My final outcome is to bring the sharepoint online data and display it in the on-premise SSRS reports.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online is quite different under the hood from SharePoint on-premises, it utilises Azure SQL databases for example.

To migrate your content from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online, you would normally use migration software such as the [SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool) or other third party migration tools such as [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/). Alternatively, you can migrate content yourself by writing your own migration functionality, using either the Microsoft Graph API or SharePoint API.

Comment: Thank you Callum,
Can I ask you how do we bring the sharepoint online data back to on-premise for SSRS reports.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest SSRS integration with SharePoint Online isn't supported: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274335/how-does-sharepoint-now-interact-with-power-bi-and-ssrs I would recommend looking at Power BI as a more modern reporting solution. If the above answer helped, please do remember to upvote or mark it as the answer so that the community can benefit from the information.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint uses online cloud. Based on your description, I understand that you want to migrate contents from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online. You could use SPMT to migrate contents.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for your response Emily,
So that means, If I use SPMT as a migration tool. and migrate the data. Does it also migrate WSS_Content database as well. Or does migration tool only migrates the documents and not the content database.
How do we bring the database from online to display data in ON-PREMISE SSRS.

Comment: SPMT will not migrate all contents in the database from 2013 to Online. It will migrate such as list, library, uers, workflows and so on.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.